# How to close a file in haskell

Tags: file, haskell

I have a problem with haskell...
I'm opening a file in haskell and after that I want add some text inside that file.

```
ame :: IO ()

ame = do
    putStr "Enter the file name: "
    name <- getLine
    file <- readFile name
    putStrLn "Do you want to add new records? "
    question <- getLine
    if question == "yes" then do
        putStrLn "Enter your records:"
        newRec <- getLine
        file <- writeFile name (file ++ newRec)

        putStrLn "a"
    else
        putStr "b"
```

this is my code. when I want to add(write) something new in my file, I receive this error...
"openFile: resource busy (file is locked)". 
how exactly can I solve this? I've been told that this appears because I don't close the file.. but how exactly can I close it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `readFile` makes use of "lazy IO", a somewhat controversial feature of the Haskell language (note: "lazy IO" is not the same as "lazy evaluation").

When you say `file <- readFile name`, the file isn't actually read at that point. Instead, the file is read once you evaluate the resulting string `file`. Scanning your program, we see that the point where you evaluate `file` is only here:

```
file <- writeFile name (file ++ newRec)
```

The function `writeFile` doesn't return anything, so what you actually mean is probably this instead:

```
writeFile name (file ++ newRec)
```

So you're reading the file called `name` when you try to write the *same* file. This is what's causing the file lock exception.

#### Solution 1 (recommended)

Rather than reading and writing an entire file just to append something to the end, just use the appropriate function:

```
appendFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()
```

Behaves like `writeFile`, but appends to the end. No need to first read the file. Your code becomes:

```
ame = do
    putStr "Enter the file name: "
    name <- getLine
    putStrLn "Do you want to add new records? "
    question <- getLine
    if question == "yes" then do
        putStrLn "Enter your records:"
        newRec <- getLine
        appendFile name newRec
        putStrLn "a"
    else
        putStr "b"
```

#### Solution 2 (ad-hoc fix)

You can also prevent the problem by making sure the entire file contents are evaluated prior to writing the file. Then, the file will be closed after reading before you start writing. There are several ways to do this. Here's one:

```
import Control.DeepSeq
import Control.Exception

ame :: IO ()
ame = do
    putStr "Enter the file name: "
    name <- getLine
    file <- readFile name
    evaluate (force file)
    putStrLn "Do you want to add new records? "
    question <- getLine
    if question == "yes" then do
        putStrLn "Enter your records:"
        newRec <- getLine
        file <- writeFile name (file ++ newRec)
        putStrLn "a"
    else
        putStr "b"
```

The important new line is `evaluate (force file)` which causes the entire contents of `file` to be evaluated at this point.

Comment: thanks. it did work. but I have another question now..I add new records in my file. but it puts these records on the same line. is there a way to put these records on separate lines?

Comment: To put records on separate lines, just include newlines where you want them. For example, `appendFile name ('\n':newRec)`

Answer (score -1):

`writeFile` returns `IO()` ,  http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=writeFile

just do `writeFile name (file ++ newRec)` without `file <-`

also you don't need to close file after `readFile`, you only need close it when you do `openFile` and then you must do `hClose file`